# Unable to access `File Path` which has spaces in perl

Tags: perl

I have similar problem where I am trying to access the current working directory as spaces like

`"C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/ISG_Regression_Testing/workspace"`

And I tried with all the solutions provided above and but did not work. My code snippet as below:

```
local @ARGV = ( "ISG_Programs.txt" );
 my $cwd = getcwd();
 my $inputPath = "$cwd/Sources/Tools/ISGTool/ISG_REGRESSION_TESTS/$ARGV[0]";
 print $inputPath;
 die "Missing file: $ARGV[0]\n" unless -e $inputPath;
```

Please someone can provide solution on this one.

Comment: `my $cwd = getcwd();  $cwd = "\"$cwd\"";` or `$inputPath = "\"$inputPath\"";`

Comment: What _similar problem_ and what _solutions provided above_ and _what error_ did you get?

Comment: @Sudharshan DS, You are mistaken. That code works fine.

Comment: @sudharshan: please update what error you have noticed.

Answer (score 1):

I created the similar folder -structure and file into my system (running Win10) and ran the code:

```
use Cwd;

local @ARGV = ( "ISG_Programs.txt" );
my $cwd = getcwd();
my $inputPath = "$cwd/Sources/Tools/ISGTool/ISG_REGRESSION_TESTS/$ARGV[0]";
print $inputPath;
die "Missing file: $ARGV[0]\n" unless -e $inputPath;
```

It seems to work ok, I get the following output:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/ISG_Regression_Testing/workspace/Sources/Tools/ISGTool/ISG_REGRESSION_TESTS/ISG_Programs.txt
```

Could you please check whether the path to the file is ok? Do you get the correct output in "print $inputPath;" -phase?

Perl should automatically escape whitespaces, thus they should not be an issue, i.e. your code looks ok. Are you running it from: C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/ISG_Regression_Testing/workspace?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to `print` its ok. While fetching or opening from the file from the path it should not. And if you doing conversion is not success. Please check once again.

Comment: @ssr1012 What do you mean? `$filename='file with blanks.txt'; open(my $fh, '<', $filename)` works like a charm. I think the OP has a totally different problem, perhaps he's in the wrong directory or mistyped the filename.

Comment: @ssr1012, Both of your comments are completely wrong. /// c0mm4, I suspect the OP actually did something like `system("foo $inputPath")` instead of using the multi-arg version of `system` or Win32::ShellQuote.

Comment: @ikegami: The issues is spaces in file path or file name that's it I should think.

Comment: @ssr1012, Again, you are mistaken. -e and open expect file paths. Any path. Path with spaces are no problem because they are paths. Adding quotes as you suggest would form an illegal path, and would cause -e and open to fail.